# babel: ReferenceError: _regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, babeljs

I'm trying to setup a Webpack-Babel-JavaScript project. It keeps failing if both async function and generator function are defined in source in this order. If the order of function definitions is changed, it runs correctly. What causes this problem? **Is there any way how to use both async and generator functions in arbitrary order with babel?**

The project uses [async-to-generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) babel plugin to convert async functions to generators and [transform-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/) plugin to transpile generator functions. I'd prefer to use babel-runtime to babel-polyfill.

Error message:

```
/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:8231
    var _marked = [foo].map(_regeneratorRuntime.mark);
                            ^

ReferenceError: _regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:8231:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:30:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:58:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:30:30)
    at /tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:50:18
    at /tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:53:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:3:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/babel-demo/dist/main.bundle.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

Project structure ([download project](https://uploadfiles.io/86a331)):

```
.
├── .babelrc
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── main.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

main.js

```javascript
async function bar(p) {
}

function* foo(p) {
}
```

Command used to recompile and run the file: `rm -rf dist && npm run build && node -p 'c = require(\"./dist/main.bundle.js\"); console.log(c)'`.

working main.js (functions are swapped)

```javascript
function* foo(p) {
}

async function bar(p) {
}
```

.babelrc

```json
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": [ "transform-async-to-generator", ["transform-runtime", {
        "helpers": false,
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true}]]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```javascript
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "babel-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "rm -rf dist && webpack && node -p 'c = require(\"./dist/main.bundle.js\"); console.log(c)'"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

It seems that in the [transpilled file](http://pastebin.com/VGkWFZqA) module 300 (starting at line 8256) defines global variable `regeneratorRuntime`. However failing line 8231 expects `_regeneratorRuntime` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem (`_regeneratorRuntime not defined` exactly), which happened only when build was produced in the environment with older node (in that case it was node `v4.4.0` on the build server). At the moment of writing, current stable node version is `v7.9`, which produced working build.

I was able to resolve it without upgrade (as a tmp fix) by eliminating some  generator or/and ES6 Polyfill methods:

- redux saga [running in parallel](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel.md) syntax
- using generators and any of the ES6 Polyfill methods (Array.find, JSON.x, Promise) in the same file